# Link CSS changes depending on URL and keeps style on sub-URLs

Tags: php, css

I am dealing with the following kind of choppy code while trying to figure this out.

```
<?php $curURL = ROOT.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
            <li><a href="<?php $href = APP_ROOT; echo $href; ?>" class="<?php if($href == $curURL) { ?>main_active<?php } ?>">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php $href = APP_ROOT.'about'; echo $href; ?>" class="<?php if($href == $curURL) { ?>main_active<?php } ?>">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php $href = APP_ROOT.'portfolio'; echo $href; ?>" class="<?php if($href == $curURL) { ?>main_active<?php } ?>">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php $href = APP_ROOT.'services'; echo $href; ?>" class="<?php if($href == $curURL) { ?>main_active<?php } ?>">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php $href = APP_ROOT.'blog'; echo $href; ?>" class="<?php if($href == $curURL) { ?>main_active<?php } ?>">BLOG</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php $href = APP_ROOT.'contact'; echo $href; ?>" class="<?php if($href == $curURL) { ?>main_active<?php } ?>">CONTACT</a></li>
```

The result I am currently getting is that if I am on the selected pages url `(ex. http://localhost/myapp/index/)` then it will change the css style accordingly. What I am looking to have happen is that the css style will remain changed even if I am on a sub url of that page `(ex. http://localhost/myapp/index/dosomething/)`. Ive been banging my head against the wall on this one for a while.

Comment: Just to comment on my above post that I do have the paths to the constants that are defined in the code above. My plan is to add this to a method when I've figured out how to get everything working correctly. Figure separating the HTML and PHP as much as possible will help the mess out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it on one of my sites. This is a sample that applies a class to an active link, but the idea is the same...

PHP

```
$current_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$fullPath = parse_url($current_url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$prepare = explode('/',$fullPath);
$path = "/" . $prepare[1];
```

HTML

```
<li><a href="location.php"<?php if($path == $thePath) { echo 'class="active"';}?>>Link Title</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is to deconstruct the path and see what the structure is. For example if the path is myapp/index/dosomething, take that path and create an array by splitting the string with "/". Then check to see what array[2] is and set your styles according to that.